# 何が「The lady doth protest to much, methinks」の日本語の対等なの？

Tags: phrase-requests

何が、ハムレットからの「The lady doth protest to much, methinks」の日本語の対等なの？

私の日本語はよくないなら、すみません。

Comment: I answered and was about to comment that maybe  you should rephrase the question to meet the standards.. 24 seconds after it was put on hold. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://james.3zoku.com/shakespeare/hamlet/hamlet3.2.2.html) reference:

> 王妃{おうひ}が大{おお}げさに誓{ちか}いすぎるように思いますが。

This version does not include the word "doth", hope it works OK for you anyway (apparently not all versions of the Hamlet have it).